# Z3 fractional exponent bug (maybe)

Tags: z3, exponent

Running Z3 on the following sequence of propositions

```
(declare-const x Real)
(assert (= 1 (^ x (/ 1 2))))
(check-sat-using qfnra-nlsat)
(get-model)
(eval (= x (^ x (/ 1 2))))
```

produces

```
sat
(model
    (define-fun x () Real
        (- 1.0)) 
)
Z3(5, 25): ERROR: even root of negative number is not real
```

Note that the final line simply evaluates the equation from line 2 on the proposed solution for x, so Z3 seems to contradict itself. Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Comment: Strangely, replacing 1/2  with 1/3 in the exponent produces the correct solution x=1.

Comment: The odd roots 1, 1/3, 1/5,... appear to produce the correct solution x=1, while the even roots 1/2, 1/4, 1/6,... produce x=-1. Irreducible fractional powers such as 2/3, 3/4, ... also produce x=-1

Comment: For bug reports please create a new issue in our issue tracker here: https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/issues Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example exposes some bugs in the facilities dealing with root objects. A fix has been checked into the master branch (Z3 now returns unknown for this tactic).